# What transformation could I still try to approach normality?

Tags: r, data-transformation

[image]

[image]

More context: these are the residuals from a mixed model where the response variable is a % that varies between 60% and 95%.

Have tried the following transformations:

1. Log
2. Sqrt (and variations)
3. 1/x (and variations)
4. arcsin (after transforming % to values between 0 and 1)
5. Yeo-Johnson

Comment: What kind of regression did you do? Did you do a beta-regression given that you work on percentages?

Comment: I think @dpathier is on the right track by trying to find the appropriate regression model that makes the right distributional assumptions.  However, if you're looking for a transformation in the linear model context, you could try estimating the power for a power transformation with a Box-Cox model.  Or you could transform your percentages into proportions and transform them using the inverse logistic CDF (e.g., `qlogis(p)` in R).

Comment: If you are fitting a mixed model, the overall distribution of the residuals remaining won't be normal. It will only be normal when you look at the distribution of the residuals, given the fitted values.

Comment: If your data is a percentage (and you have observed percentages close to 0 % or 100 %), you should fit a GLMM with appropriate distribution family, maybe beta-regression.

Comment: Why do you think the distribution should look like a Normal curve?

Comment: ... and even if it ought to look Normal, often that doesn't even matter, depending on what you are trying to infer from this analysis.  What can be said immediately, though, is that none of your efforts will succeed, because your problem is heavy tails, not a skewed distribution.  Moreover, the relative range of the data is so short -- it's less than half the mid-value -- that no general family of transformations will be helpful.  If perhaps there's something special about the extreme values of 60% and 95%, you might be able to exploit that.  We need details.